# Having trouble doubling up with two regular Expressions

Tags: python

I have a work project I am trying to write some Python code for to automate a data set that I need on a monthly basis.  I have approximately 300-400 different records coming in a random  text file. I have no ability to modify the way the data comes to me each month but I need to pull out about half of them into a separate text file to hand off to another person.  In the past we have been splitting them manually but I would much like to automate this process. I am very new to python and hope to learn in the process of making this script.

I have written a small script that uses a Regular Expression to pull out each section and then a second Regular Expression to determine if it fits the criteria to be placed in the separate file.  However what I have written only pulls the line instead of the entire section.  I have made multiple changes and cannot seem to figure out what will allow me to pull the entire first match instead of just the line on the second one.

```
pattern = re.compile('^START[\S\s]*END$',re.MULTILINE)

ccgjju = re.compile('WNO/CC[\S\s]',re.MULTILINE)

filetowrite = 'ccgjju.txt'

tempFile = open(filetowrite, 'a' )

for pattern in open('source.txt'):

    if ccgjju.match(pattern):

        tempFile.write(pattern)

tempFile.close()
```

My source file contains 300-500 records similar to this

```
START
NAME/SMITH,JOHN SEX/M RAC/W
MIS/RANDOM INFORMATION
WNO/CC124589 DAT/01012019
ADDR/121 MAIN ST
END

START
NAME/THOMPSON,JOHN SEX/M RAC/W
MIS/RANDOM INFORMATION
WNO/DC0123456 DAT/01012019
ADDR/121 MAIN ST
END

START
NAME/THOMAS,JOHN SEX/M RAC/W
MIS/RANDOM INFORMATION
WNO/CC01234 DAT/01012019
ADDR/121 MAIN ST
END
```

I want it to pull everything between the START and END if the WNO/CC line has the WNO/CC instead of WNO/DC. Currently it will return the following to the output file instead of the entire record between the two.

```
WNO/CC124589 DAT/01012019
WNO/CC01234 DAT/01012019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are reading line by line, you'll not hit a match. Try:

```
with open('source.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

# get the blocks between START and END
blocks = re.findall(r'START([\s\S]*?)END', s, re.M)

# same as
blocks = re.findall(r'START(.*?)END', s, re.M|re.S)

# get the blocks that match WNO/CC
res = [b for b in blocks if re.findall(r'WNO/CC', b)]
```

Use `*?` to get shortest match instead of a greedy match.

Comment: You can use `.` instead of `[\s\S]` if you add `re.DOTALL` to the flags. Also, you could combine the regexes, no need to do it in two steps.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Good catch. I'll improve it.

Comment: This fixed my problem.  I am now able to get the entire text between the start and end.  What normally will be a 3-4 hour monthly process I think i can make about 10 minutes.  This is amazing.

Comment: @Tkmelz You're welcome. However, I couldn't combining the regex correctly, maybe someone else could fix it ;) But for a 300-400 blocks case it's fine.

Comment: I simplified my problem.  I have about 8 different pieces of text that could all be found inside the blocks.  and those pieces will each determine which of 6 files they go into.  I think the most I get every month is 540 records right now but this will definitely get me pointed in the right direction.  I actually already ran it on the big file and it worked perfectly.  Now just to modify it to pull the rest of them out to individual files.

Comment: I had in mind something like `re.findall(r'START(?:(?!END).)*WNO/CC.*?END', s, re.M | re.S)` ([code](https://regex101.com/r/RBi818/1)), but yeah it got complicated making sure it wouldn't consume multiple blocks. Two steps is fine as well and it's easier to read.